# React-Native flexDirection: 'row' with multiple lines

Tags: react-native

I would like to know if there is a way to have `flexDirection: 'row'` with multiple lines. Because now if I have 10 objects in row non will go on a second line. This is the example from documentation where I've added another two `<View>` elements

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FlexDirectionBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Try setting `flexDirection` to `column`.
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
};

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FlexDirectionBasics);
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `flex-wrap: wrap` so the content will break to a new line when it reaches the max width allowed for this component.

```
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
      </View>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Hope it helps

Comment: great , one more important thing though , if above code is wrapped into a View /ScrollView component we must add flex: 1 with it too to make it work.